# Windows Form's Layout Properties Get Updated Automatically in Design Mode

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

Every time I open a Win Form in designer, its ClientSize property changes along with the child controls' Margin and Location properties. How can I prevent this from happening?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: This bug has been around since Visual Studio 2002. I'm really disappointed that Microsoft hasn't figured it out yet.

Comment: It was most likely designed on another machine with a different DPI setting.  So does the proper job at design-time as well, it rescales itself to fit the current machine's DPI.  Easiest way to diagnose this is look at the InitializeComponent() method near the bottom, this.AutoScaleDimensions property assignment.  Compare the values with a brand new form.  You can hack the values to match but then you'll have to re-layout the form.

Comment: @HansPassant you are absolutely right. I was just confused by the outcome of this behavior. namely, why it displays the form normally (properly rescaled) in Designer, but in runtime it looks distorted and magnified...